# Creates user- defined function with multiple vectors and obtains the mean and variance

Tags: python, function, statistics, mean, variance

I am trying to define the Python function - obtains the mean and variance with given multiple vectors. There are only x-axis and y-axis.

I tried make some functions and created the code but it showed me just an incorrect value.

Below is my code.

```
def avr(*inn):
    hap = 0
    cnt = 0
    for i in inn:
        hap += i
        cnt += 1
    avrr = hap/cnt

    return avrr

def varr(*inn):
    jejob = 0
    jegobhap = 0
    cnt = 0
    for i in inn:
        cha = (i-avr(*inn))
        jegob = cha**2
        jegobhap += jegob
        cnt += 1
    varr_m = jegobhap/cnt

    return varr_m

def mean_and_var(*val):
    x_axis_avr = avr(*val[0])
    y_axis_avr = avr(*val[1])
    x_axis_boon = varr(*val[0])
    y_axis_boon = varr(*val[1])

    return ((x_axis_avr,y_axis_avr),(x_axis_boon,y_axis_boon))

v1=(0,1)
v2=(0.5, 0.5)
v3=(1,0)
v4=(50,30)

m, var = mean_and_var(v1,v2,v3,v4)
print("mean: ", m, "var: " , var)
```

and it gives me

```
mean: (0.5, 0.5) var: (0.25, 0.0)
```

The correct value should be;

```
mean (12.875, 7.875) var: (459.546875,163.296875)
```

What is the error?

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables in different places - and compare these values with your calculations on paper. It will help you find place with problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you expect too much for Python.

`var[0]` gives first vector `(0,1)`, not first values from all vectors `(0, 0.5, 1, 50)`.

`var[1]` gives second vector `(0.5, 0.5)`, not second values from all vectors `(1, 0.5, 0, 30)`

And it doesn't use values `v3, v4`

Try this and you get expected values

```
v1 = (0, 0.5, 1, 50)
v2 = (1, 0.5, 0, 30)

m, var = mean_and_var(v1, v2)
print("mean: ", m, "var: " , var)
```

---

**EDIT:** using `numpy` you can do something like this

(I removed all `*` before variables)

```
def avr(inn): # * removed
    #print('avr:', inn)

    hap = 0
    cnt = 0
    for i in inn:
        hap += i
        cnt += 1
    avrr = hap/cnt

    return avrr

def varr(inn): # * removed
    #print('varr:', inn)

    jejob = 0
    jegobhap = 0
    cnt = 0
    for i in inn:
        cha = (i-avr(inn)) # * removed
        jegob = cha**2
        jegobhap += jegob
        cnt += 1
    varr_m = jegobhap/cnt

    return varr_m

def mean_and_var(val):
    x_axis_avr = avr(val[:,0]) # * removed
    y_axis_avr = avr(val[:,1]) # * removed
    x_axis_boon = varr(val[:,0]) # * removed
    y_axis_boon = varr(val[:,1]) # * removed

    return (x_axis_avr, y_axis_avr), (x_axis_boon, y_axis_boon)

import numpy as np

v1 = (0, 1)
v2 = (0.5, 0.5)
v3 = (1, 0)
v4 = (50, 30)

matrix = np.array([v1,v2,v3,v4])
#print(matrix)

m, var = mean_and_var(matrix)
print("mean: ", m, "var: " , var)
```